# UICollectionViewCell cell alignment Top Left

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to align all the cells in the to left (0,0).  But now its aligned in the center of the row. 
all the cell heights are dynamic as per the content size.

[image]